# HttpClient and form parameter names

Tags: http, .net-core

This code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) })
{
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        content.Add(new StringContent("abc"), "token");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost", content);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Generates the following HTTP request:

```
POST http://localhost/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="4b39ed14-752b-480a-9846-fc0019132d15"
Content-Length: 174

--4b39ed14-752b-480a-9846-fc0019132d15
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=token

abc
--4b39ed14-752b-480a-9846-fc0019132d15--
```

We have a client who says their WAF is blocking the request because the name parameter should be quoted

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"
```

I have seen some differences in opinion on this:

https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/18788
https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/386

Does anyone know what is correct here?

Comment: Examples I can find all seem to use quoted strings for the name value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition. It feels to me like HTTPClient is not compliant with standards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this to https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72447

Either form is correct, apparently